# Надо ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Его Сиятельство граф Воронов И.Л.
Надо ли ставить запятую после слова "Сиятельство"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна, так как здесь встречаются титулование и титул, они не являются однородными приложениями. Его/Ваше Сиятельство - титулование, форма обращения. Граф - титул.

Сравните с сочетанием ученой степени и звания (они рассматриваются как однородные приложения): *доктор математических наук, профессор Иванов.*

А другие сочетания (должности/профессии и др. с ученой степенью/званием) не однородны, так как характеризуют предмет с разных сторон: *заведующий кафедрой доктор математических наук Иванов, известный лингвист профессор Иванов.*

Еще примеры: *начальник лаборатории кандидат химических наук Нечаев; кандидат технических наук капитан-инженер Михайлов; экс-чемпион мира по шахматам гроссмейстер Карпов.*

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, здесь запятая не нужна, потому что нет перечисления. Его сиятельство граф - это, фактически, цельная конструкция.

Comment: Я так примерно и думала, но не могла сформулировать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Помнится,читал правило о том, что подобные конструкции связаны с одиночным приложением. Запятая ставится, если определяемое слово и приложение идентичны друг другу, например, кандидат наук, доцент Иванов. Логика такова: кандидат наук и доцент обычно сопоставительные характеристики, поэтому нужна запятая. А вот "кандидат наук заведующий кафедрой" не обязательно предполагают друг друга, поэтому запятая не требуется. Думаю, "Его Сиятельство" и "граф" - близкие понятия, поэтому считаю, что запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Если подходить с точки зрения пауз, чем частенько обосновывает свои ответы [@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), запятую надо ставить. Представляете: на митинге объявляют Путина: "Президент Российской Федерации (длинная многозначительная пауза), Главнокомандующий Вооруждёнными Силами России Владимир Владимирович  (на полном выдохе воздуха из лёгких! голосовые связки в динамическом напряжении!) П У-У-У Т И Н !!!" После "Федерации" постановка запятой обязательна.

Comment: Специально для Вас делаем паузу и ставим запятую: "Ваше сиятельство, господин граф!" – воскликнул он, вставая и делая вид, что страшно удивлен этим неожиданным появлением (Ж. Санд. Консуэло). Но это исключение. Обычно ни паузы, ни запятые при обращении к сиятельным графам не предусмотрены, например: "Его сиятельству господину министру внутренних дел графу Льву Алексеевичу Перовскому состоящего при министерстве надворного советника Аксакова рапорт".